# Finitely generated module as a quotient of a free module of finite rank

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If an $R$-module $M$ is generated by $n$ elements then how to show that $M$ can be realised as a quotient of $R^n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be generators of $M$, and define $f:R^n\to M$ by $$f(r_1,\ldots,r_n)=r_1x_1+\cdots+r_nx_n.$$
This is a surjective $R$-module homomorphism from $R^n$ to $M$. Is there a homomorphism theorem you can apply here to realize $M$ as a quotient of $R^n$?